# How can I remove duplicates from one List<T> that are found in another?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0

This is for .NET 2.0, so I cannot use LINQ.

I have a bit of an interesting problem.

I am merging two lists of custom type "Article".

The below code does the job nicely:

```
List<Article> merge = new List<Article>(GetFeatureArticles());
merge.AddRange(result);

return merge;
```

GetFeatureArticle has only 2 items that are the first two elements in the merged list. 
"result" is large and its elements trail "GetFeatureArticle"'s elements.

The problem is that I need to compare the list returned from "GetFeatureArticles()"
to the list in "result" and, if there is a match, remove the matched item in result, not 
in "GetFeatureArticles". Both lists are of type `List<Article>.`

I am limited by C# 2.0 unfortunately.

Thank you.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

This is the implementation I ultimately went with as GetFeaturedArticles()
will always be two items:

```
List<Article> k = new List<Article>(GetFeatureArticles());

            foreach (Article j in k)
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < tiles.Count; i++ )
                {
                    if (j.ID == tiles[i].ID)
                        tiles.Remove(tiles[i]);
                }
            }

            k.AddRange(tiles);

            return k;
```

Comment: since this is a custom type - what constitutes a match?

Comment: limited by .NEt 2.0 or C# 2.0 (your tags suggests .net 2.0 and you text c#2.0)

Comment: How come you are limited to .Net 2.0?

Comment: Since I'm not too "hip" on LINQ, how would this be solved with it?

Comment: @Hans Gruber for example `return merge.Union(result);`

Comment: @Yahia - Great thanks!  I believe an investment in LINQ learning is needed, it looks like it will simplify my code dramatically.

Comment: @Hans Gruber for starters see the samples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: @Hans Gruber - LINQ is great, but for a simple switch from an imperative style, try using the methods on the list class, or the static Array. methods. They do so much of the same thing. For loops are antiquated.

Comment: Eeeep.... for loops and imperative code. eep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
List<Article> g = new List<Article>(GetFeatureArticles());

foreach (Article a in g)
{
if (result.Contains (a))
    result.Remove (a);
}

g.AddRange (result);

return g;
```

EDIT - as per comments:

I assume that `Article` is a reference type and is implemented with suitable `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods respectively - otherwise the above would only work for equal references (= "same object in both Lists")...

Comment: I assume `Article` is a reference type so this would only work if the items in `g` and the items in `result` point to the same references

Comment: Which relates to @BrokenGlass question in the comments

Comment: @BrokenGlass, or if the type implements `IEquatable<T>`. Or if it overrides `object.Equals()`.

Comment: @Yahia, thanks. I had to weak this (in my edit) but you set me down the right road so i gave you the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have some sort of object equality implemented.

```cs
var listA = new List<Article> {a, b, c, d};
var listB = new List<Article> {e, f}; //Where e, f are equal to b, c in a.
listA.RemoveAll(listB.Contains);
```

Comment: PS - If you don't have LINQ, the List class has quite a few methods that are provided by LINQ, and a ForEach...

Comment: Hi Ritch. Thanks. I feel like this should work. It makes complete sense but when I try it it fails - I still see the repeat instance of the Article item. Can you tell me how exactly the Contains method is determining repetition?

Comment: @Code Sherpa - Read the first sentence. You have to provide the equality semantics for your types ('Article' in this example). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx

Comment: Thanks a ton Ritch. I upvoted you but the solution i went with was ultimately different. You helped a ton though, much appreciated!

Comment: @Code Sherpa - I'm interested to see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

```
returnList = returnList.Union(ListToAdd).ToList();
```

or if combinging multiple lists of items...

```
foreach (List<ListItem> l in ListsToAdd)
{
    returnList = returnList.Union(l).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a `Dictionary` from the `result` set. Then:

```
foreach (Article a featuredArticles)
{
    if (resultsDictionary.ContainsKey(a.Key))
    {
        resultsDictionary.Remove(a.Key);
    }
}
```

Then convert the dictionary back to a list.

Answer (score 0):

This works against .NET Framework 2.0:

```
var featured = new List<Article>(GetFeaturedArticles());

result.RemoveAll(featured.Contains);

result.InsertRange(0, featured);

return result;
```

Comment: Note that your code won't compile with the 2.0 compiler, as Lambda expressions didn't exist in the language then. I take it that, if you compile with .NET 2.0 as the target, the compiler "does the right thing"?

Comment: @Jim - it does. But I've changed the lambda to a method group.